# Distinct with order by for different columns and hstore rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to do this query:

Got models `user`, `profile`, `integrations`

`Profile` has a column `meta_data` that is hstore and has key `twitter_followers`

This is my current query which I want to do an order for:

```
current_user.profiles.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON(profiles.id) profiles.id, *, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers, profiles.*").includes(:integrations).page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
```

Ideally:

```
current_user.profiles.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON(profiles.id) profiles.id, *, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers, profiles.*").includes(:integrations).reorder("CAST(meta_data -> '#{params[:sort_by]}' AS INT) DESC NULLS LAST").page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
```

But get this error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

I tried this:

```
current_user.profiles.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON(profiles.id) profiles.id, *, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers, profiles.*").includes(:integrations).reorder("profiles.id, CAST(meta_data -> '#{params[:sort_by]}' AS INT) DESC NULLS LAST").page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
```

`.to_sql`

```
=> "SELECT DISTINCT ON(profiles.id) profiles.id, *, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers, profiles.* FROM \"profiles\" INNER JOIN \"integration_profiles\" ON \"profiles\".\"id\" = \"integration_profiles\".\"profile_id\" INNER JOIN \"integrations\" ON \"integration_profiles\".\"integration_id\" = \"integrations\".\"id\" WHERE \"integrations\".\"user_id\" = $1 AND \"profiles\".\"found\" = 't'  ORDER BY profiles.id, CAST(meta_data -> 'twitter_followers' AS INT) DESC NULLS LAST"
```

And no dice. It removed the error but didn't order in any form!

Comment: Use "ORDER BY profiles.id, your_other_conditions" in your query. Every column in the DISTINCT ON (), must be used in the ORDER BY

Comment: I did try that and the query is under 'I tried this: '

Comment: Could you show us the SQL that is generated?

Comment: it should be ordered by the profiles.id and then by twitter_followers. If you expect ordering by twitter_followers first, distinct on() doesn't work because it requires an initial order by on the distinct columns.

Comment: But isn't that what I did with `.reorder("profiles.id, CAST(meta_data -> '#{params[:sort_by]}' AS INT) DESC NULLS LAST")`

Comment: `CAST(meta_data -> 'twitter_followers' AS INT)` is not being called or happening!